# Нет ли ошибки в предложении с придаточным?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли ошибка в данном примере: "Тебе не следует ждать, что у нас всё вернётся на прежний лад"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше ***ожидать***.
Ждать — обычно кого-то/что-то не абстрактное.
Значения "*ждать*" точно нет, иначе было бы "*ждать того, что*".

"*Следует*" лучше заменить на ***стоит*** (стилистика лучше).
*Не следует — не нужно.* || Не сильно подходит.
*Не стоит — нет смысла.*

Лучше звучит глагол ***рассчитывать***:
*Тебе не стоит рассчитывать, что у нас всё вернётся на прежний лад.*